# Where is CONFIG_HZ defined?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, c

I'm in the middle of reading the whole [Linux 5.0.7 source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git), and I've noticed something strange. I'll refer to `linux` as the parent directory here, correct me if the community uses some other naming convention in the literature.

In the file `linux/include/asm-generic/param.h`, the value `CONFIG_HZ` is used. The value is not defined in the previous lines, and the only included file is `uapi/asm-generic/param.h`. I believe this refers to `linux/include/uapi/asm-generic/param.h`, again, correct me if I'm wrong.

In that file, no such value as `CONFIG_HZ` is ever defined. Now, in your average C program, this would cause a bug. We have 3 options here:

- I misunderstood something and `linux/include/asm-generic/param.h` actually includes another file where the value IS defined.
- This is a bug, and I am a genius for discovering it (least likely option).
- There is some "magic" going on, like some macros that Linux defines before, or some files the kernel includes before including `linux/include/asm-generic/param.h` where the value is defined, so that when `linux/include/asm-generic/param.h` is called the value is already defined. In this case, please point me to what this file is.

If none of these is true, what is the reason why this is a correct C program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like other `CONFIG_` values, `CONFIG_HZ` is a configuration setting; you’ll find it in [`kernel/Kconfig.hz`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/Kconfig.hz), along with various arch-specific overrides in other `Kconfig` files. Its value is determined during the build and stored in a generated configuration file, `include/generated/autoconf.h`.

The latter is included by the kernel’s build command. To see this in action, pick a file which includes `asm/param.h`, and build its post-processed equivalent, verbosely; for example

```
make drivers/atm/suni.i V=1
```

At some point in the build you’ll see

```
gcc -E -Wp,-MD,drivers/atm/.suni.i.d  -nostdinc \
    -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/include \
    -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated \
    -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi \
    -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi \
    -I./include/generated/uapi \
    -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h \
    -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h ...
    -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"suni"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"suni"' \
    -o drivers/atm/suni.i drivers/atm/suni.c
```

and you can see the result in `drivers/atm/suni.i`, with the expansion of `HZ` and `CONFIG_HZ`.

The `-include ./include/linux/kconfig.h` directive ensures that the kernel configuration is always included. [`include/linux/kconfig.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/kconfig.h) includes `generated/autoconf.h`.

Comment: And I suppose `include/generated/autoconf.h` is included in the kernel's execution flow before `linux/include/asm-generic/param.h`?

Comment: @memememe yes, the kernel configuration is included first.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of programs (like vim e.g., or firefox) have many compile options. For different reasons you **can or have to** choose some options at compile time.

For linux you have a whole system: the `config` family of `make` *Configuration targets* to configure the Kconfig "symbols" in a logical hierarchical way, with good explanations (online help). Because there are a lot of dependencies, intra- and extraplatform. Even just by paging through or grepping these Kconfig* files, which are "spread" all over, you get basic info ("if unsure, say yes", "if you have never heard of X, simply choose no")

I had a hard time finding this "HZ" from inside `make nconfig`. In the end it is `F8` for "SymSearch", type "HZ" (with or without CONFIG_ it says -- this is very user friendly!), and you get search results like:

```
    | Symbol: HZ_100 [=n]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    | Prompt: 100 HZ                                                                                                                                             
    |   Location:                                                                                                                                             
    |     -> Processor type and features                                                                                                                       
    |       -> Timer frequency (<choice> [=y])                                                                                                                 
    |   Defined at kernel/Kconfig.hz:19
```

So the **Timer frequency** is a submenu of "Processor type...". This ncurses popup "window" contains the relevant info to "where is HZ defined".  ("Location:" and "Defined at")

---

Just by checking where these 19 Kconfigs lie (their directory names) you get a good impression. `Kconfig.hz` in `./kernel/` is one of them.

```
  ]# find kernel mm block init ipc -name "Kconfig*" |wc
     19      19     376
```

---

So after you choose a time slice ("jiffy") value from kernel/Kconfig.hz (a separete file!), `make` will somehow (Kbuild) prepare for the actual compiler `gcc` call. (see other answer for details).

So **yes, some kind of magic**, a selfmade preprocessor (partly in C source code!) for the gcc preprocessor.

CONFIG_xxx are mostly used as boolean #ifdefs (conditional compilation --- orthogonal to if...else).

---

> ...middle of reading the whole Linux 5.0.7 source code

```
]# find arch/x86/ include -name param.h   

arch/x86/include/uapi/asm/param.h
include/uapi/linux/param.h
include/uapi/asm-generic/param.h
include/asm-generic/param.h
```

There is a fine line between "make magic" and "header soup". Thanks to your hints I found a nice find-prune-grep sequence. Knowing #preprocessor and CONFIG_ is one thing. Some brute force is sometimes necessary; for a full search, pruning drivers/ is often a good idea. By having all arch/* dirs included, this shows how special alpha is.

**And how precise you went for that asm-generic "#define HZ" in param.h:**

```
]# find -name drivers -prune -o -name '*.[ch]' -exec grep "\<CONFIG_HZ\>" {} +  

./arch/alpha/kernel/time.c:     clockevents_config_and_register(ce, CONFIG_HZ, 0, 0);
./arch/alpha/kernel/time.c:#if CONFIG_HZ == 1024 || CONFIG_HZ == 1200
./arch/alpha/kernel/time.c:#elif CONFIG_HZ == 256 || CONFIG_HZ == 128 || CONFIG_HZ == 64 || CONFIG_HZ == 32
./arch/alpha/kernel/time.c:     sel = RTC_REF_CLCK_32KHZ + __builtin_ffs(32768 / CONFIG_HZ);
./arch/alpha/kernel/time.c:                    CONFIG_HZ, sel);
./arch/alpha/kernel/setup.c:#if CONFIG_HZ == 1024 || CONFIG_HZ == 1200
./arch/alpha/kernel/setup.c:    timer_freq = 100UL * CONFIG_HZ;
./arch/alpha/include/asm/param.h:# define HZ  CONFIG_HZ

./arch/ia64/include/asm/param.h:# define HZ  CONFIG_HZ

./include/asm-generic/param.h:# define HZ  CONFIG_HZ  /* Internal kernel timer frequency */
```

(I only touched whitespace)

The `make config` results (the direct and indirect Kconfig choices) end up in /proc (if this option is Y ;):

```
]# zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_HZ

# CONFIG_HZ_PERIODIC is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_100 is not set
# CONFIG_HZ_250 is not set
CONFIG_HZ_300=y
# CONFIG_HZ_1000 is not set
CONFIG_HZ=300
```